# undefined route in laravel module

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Am in a sidebar which is a component and have defined this in sidebar

```
$item->item('user profile', function (Item $item) {
                        $item->icon('fa fa-settings');
                        $item->route('personal.settings.details.user_info');
                        $item->authorize(true);
                    });
```

Am new to laravel modules i want to route to user_info through controller. in the web.php I have this;

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings', 'as' => 'settings.'], function () {
    Route::resource('user_info', 'UserInfoController');
});
```

How do i solve it or where can i find resources on module routing

```
class UserInfoController extends Controller
{
    protected $folder_path = 'personal::settings.details.';
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
return view($this->folder_path . 'USER_INFO', compact('data' ));
```

I want to be able to move to user_info page

Comment: it should be something like ``$item->route('personal.settings.user_info');``

Comment: Route [personal.settings.user_info] not defined. this what i get

Comment: just run `php artisan route:list` and match url and route name.

Answer (score 0):

to access your user_info route you should proceed with /settings/user_info.
if you can clarify more your question we can help.

Comment: added details @Shelby

Comment: try : 
Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings', 'as' => 'settings'], function () {
    Route::resource('user_info', 'UserInfoController');
});
and :
$item->route('settings.user_info');
don't forget php artisan optimize